# Angular HTTP subscribe não retorna response

Tags: javascript, angular

Eu criei um service para bater em minha API e retornar todos os pedidos de acordo com certo tipo params.

Quando eu tento atribuir o retorno ao meu component, ele não me retorna uma array de resultados, me retorna um subscriber.

**Service**

```
 baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001';
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 getPedidos = (tipo: Pedidos): Observable<any> => this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/pedidos?tipo=${tipo}`);
```

**Component ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.pratosPrincipais = this.getPedidos(1);
  }

  private getPedidos = (tipo) =>
  this.pedidoService.getPedidos(tipo)
  .subscribe(pedido => pedido)
```

Ao atribuir a variável, é esse o valor atribuído:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo após isso, eu passo o valor via Input para outro componente.

```
<app-expansion-panel title="Prato Principal" [data]=pratosPrincipais></app-expansion-panel>
```

**Componente expansion panel ts**

```
@Input() data;
```

tentei dar subscribe em data, mas apresenta erro que não é uma função.
Testei a api e esta funcionando normalmente.

O que estou esquecendo?

Answer (score 0):

Obervables são como uma stream de dados que emitem eventos, portanto pra obter os dados destes eventos é preciso inscrever-se na stream, o objeto retornado dessa stream é um `subscriber` (que é o objeto que está sendo associado ao `pratosPrincipais`).
No seu caso o código está inscrito mas quando a stream emite `next` (que é quando a requisição retorna) sua função que escuta ao `next` não altera nada seu escopo local, no caso seu código precisa associar o valor no escopo fora da stream:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.pedidoService.getPedidos(1)
    .subscribe(pedido => this.pratosPrincipais = pedido)
}
```

Para deixar mais claro, o `Subscriber` é o ponto no qual o **encanamento** da stream enviará os dados, é preciso de uma **ação** sempre que algo for recebido naquele encanamento.

*Sim, observables são complicadas no início mas na prática é mais fácil, veja os exemplos da [api](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview) :)*

Comment: o erro final é no seu bind [data]="pratosPrincipais"

Comment: eu tentei da forma que me disse, mas me retornou [object object]

Comment: não é essa a response?

Comment: deveria me retornar um array de objetos

Comment: o array de objetos é o [object Object], deve ser descontruído dentro da função subscribe antes de associar aos pratosPrincipais

Answer (score 0):

Sabemos que o método `HttpClient.get()` serve para buscar dados de um servidor, mesmo que pareça redundante é uma informação relevante.
O método `assíncrono` envia uma solicitação `HTTP` e retorna um `Observable` que emite os dados solicitados quando a `resposta` é recebida.
O método `get()` contem dois argumentos: a `URL` e um objeto de `opções`, porém em sua solicitação tem apenas a `URL`, passe o segundo parâmetro para sua `API` para que possa receber a resposta desejada utilizando: `{observe: 'response'}`.

Ou seja:

```
getPedidos = (tipo: Pedidos): Observable<any> => this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/pedidos?tipo=${tipo}`, {observe: 'response'});
```

Desta forma o `observe` especifica qual tipo de resposta deseja obter.

Você poderá encontrar mais informações a respeito dos tipos de retornos no site oficial do Angular: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server

Answer (score -1):

Nesse caso a sua variável pedido aparentar ser outro Obervable....

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getPedidos(1);
  }

  private getPedidos = (tipo) =>
  this.pedidoService.getPedidos(tipo)
  .subscribe(pedido => this.pratosPrincipais = pedido);
```

Ou outra opção seria converter para Promise e passar a utilizar o async/await

```
 async ngOnInit() {
   this.pratosPrincipais = await this.getPedidos(1);
  }

  private getPedidos = (tipo) =>
  this.pedidoService.getPedidos(tipo)
  .toPromise()
```

Comment: Ele me retorna "undefined" se eu fizer dessa forma.

Comment: private getPedidos = (tipo) =>
  this.pedidoService.getPedidos(tipo)
  .subscribe(pedido => this.pratosPrincipais = pedido);

ainda que faça dessa forma?

Comment: Mesmo dessa forma, tentei até retornar todo o meu resultado da api e nada